# Converting sbyte to byte

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I have a variable of type `sbyte` and would like to copy the content to a `byte`. The conversion wouldn't be a value conversion, rather a bit per bit copy.

For example,

if mySbyte in bits is: '10101100', after conversion, the corresponding byte variable will also contain the bits '10101100'.

Comment: Why not just cast it to `byte` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Will it work, I read somewhere if the value is out of range, that is negative on sbyte, will throw exception.

Comment: Well not really say its -1 then you would get it as 255

Comment: @V4Vendetta is right, you don't need `unchecked` for casting *runtime variables*. See my answer for the full details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
unchecked
{
    sbyte s;
    s= (sbyte)"your value";
    byte b=(byte)s;
}
```

More about `unchecked` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 21):

Let me clarify the `unchecked` business. The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that `unchecked` is used to prevent overflow checking, which would otherwise, **when inside a checked context**, give a compile error or throw an exception.

...**IF** inside a checked context.

The context is checked either explicitly:

```
checked { ... }
```

or implicitly*, when dealing with **compile-time constants**:

```
byte b = (byte)-6; //compile error
byte b2 = (byte)(200 + 200); //compile error

int i = int.MaxValue + 10; //compiler error
```

But when dealing with **runtime** variables, the context is **`unchecked`** by default**:

```
sbyte sb = -6;
byte b = (byte)sb; //no problem, sb is a variable


int i = int.MaxValue;
int j = i + 10;    //no problem, i is a variable
```

To summarize and answer the original question:

Need `byte<->sbyte` conversion on **constants**? Use `unchecked` and cast:

```
byte b = unchecked( (byte) -6 );
```

Need `byte<->sbyte` conversion on **variables**? Just cast:

```
sbyte sb = -6;
byte b = (byte) sb;
```

---

* There is a third way to get a checked context by default: by tweaking the compiler settings. E.g. Visual Studio -> Project properties -> Build -> Advanced... -> [X] Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow

** The runtime context is unchecked by default ***in C#***. In VB.NET for example, the default runtime context is CHECKED.

Answer (score 5):

```
unchecked
{
    sbyte s = (sbyte)250; //-6 (11111010) 
    byte b = (byte)s; //again 250 (11111010) 
}
```

Comment: Added clarification, what is meant by unchecked as used here?

Comment: Since 250 exceeds the range of sbyte(-128 - 127) an unchecked conversion is needed.

Answer (score 4):

like this:

```
sbyte sb = 0xFF;
byte b = unchecked((byte)sb);
```